# Connot hear sound when connecting my Toshiba (intel i3) Laptop to my TV

Tags: laptop, intel-graphics, hdmi, tv

I tried connecting my Toshiba laptop with Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz × 4 processor to my TV using a HDMI connector. Though I can receive images on my TV, I still get audio my laptop speakers and not my TV.

My graphics type is shown as unknown in the system settings.

Can you please help me with this?

Thank you and regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the bar at the side, you may see an application named 'System Settings'. Click on this link and then under 'Hardware', click on 'Sound'. Then, try adjusting the default audio output device for your computer. In this case, it will be HDMI Audio.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to update your graphics driver since HDMI is a digital signal for both audio and video. If you type

```
 aplay -l,
```

you should see all your audio outputs. If your HDMI output is not listed, then it is probably a driver issue. If it is listed, try using aplay commands to play a file to check if it is working. This looks something similar to

```
aplay -D hw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```